Upgrade button from software updater doesn't work?

When I press the upgrade button, the software updater window simply disappears.
Also, I've also tried
sudo do-release-upgrade

However, I get the following message:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

This, despite having already run
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

When doing the upgrade, I get:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libmagickcore-6.q16-dev vlc-plugin-qt libvlc5 vlc-data gsasl-common
  libvlccore9 libmagickwand-dev libheif1 vlc imagemagick vlc-bin vlc-l10n
  libopenexr-dev libopenexr25 libmagick++-6.q16-8 libpostproc55
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra vlc-plugin-samba libgsasl7 libavcodec58
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-notify libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16
  libswscale5 redis-tools libmagickcore-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-access-extra
  vlc-plugin-skins2 libgsl27 vlc-plugin-video-splitter libswresample3
  imagemagick-6-common vlc-plugin-video-output libmagickcore-6-arch-config
  libavformat58 heif-gdk-pixbuf libmagickwand-6-headers libgslcblas0
  libde265-0 libmagickwand-6.q16-dev libmagickcore-6-headers libvlc-bin
  vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-visualization
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  apt apt-utils build-essential cpp g++ gcc libapt-pkg6.0 python3-update-manager shim-signed update-manager
  update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Any help would be appreciated!
Addendum:
I've just found out the problem...
These packages are covered by Ubuntu Pro Securities Update. To update them, I need to create a Pro account...
WTF Ubuntu!!!


Looks Like this packages are in phased state.

This question is similar to: Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 because of The following packages have been kept back libpq5. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@karel In that question, the user clearly states that the reason for not being able to upgrade is packages being held back... I had no idea that was the underlying problem. In my perspective, the Software Updater was simply broken...

Let's look at this part of your output:
The following packages have been kept back:
  apt apt-utils build-essential cpp g++ gcc libapt-pkg6.0 python3-update-manager shim-signed update-manager
  update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

In this case, "kept back" means Phased Updates.

What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?

You have two options:

Wait. When phasing is complete, your system will be able to release upgrade normally. Phasing usually lasts less than a week, occasionally longer if problems are found. (Preventing that problem from reaching you is the whole point of phasing).

Override phasing and install now. This is not recommended, but it's your system and it's your tolerance for risk.
sudo apt update
sudo apt -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true upgrade




Many thanks!
I get the point of phased updates... However, why would the Software Updater offer me the option to update the OS, when clearly it won't? That doesn't make sense to me... If we have packages being held back, and the current settings prevent the upgrade from happening, it makes no sense to offer that option to the user. Moreover, all those packages are, in some way, I think at least, system related, i.e. Ubuntu should have all the information it needs to know when an update will be possible.

And by the way, your answer is very good, I think. Clear and well structured. Thanks +1

I opened a bug report for you. Please subscribe to the bug, and please answer the developer's questions.
